# I am running my project after 2 days and am getting an error saying I've duplicate files in the support library

Tags: android, gradle

Below is the error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/hardware/display/DisplayManagerJellybeanMr1.class
```

Below is my module level build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.aishwarya.easyreimbursement"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            resValue "string", "app_name", "Easy Reimbursement"
        }

        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "Easy Reimbursement (debug)"
        }
    }
}

/* Use 23 on 32- bit OS, as 24 onwards support for 32- bit OS has been dropped */
project.ext.supportLib = "23.2.1"

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLib"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$supportLib"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportLib"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLib"

    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

After my research I've learned that this is due to duplicate dependency files. I can check it in my project dependency tree. I tried doing that from command line but no output:

```
aishwaryat@Linux-1:~/EasyReimbursement$ gradlew app:dependencies
No command 'gradlew' found, did you mean:
 Command 'gradle' from package 'gradle' (universe)
gradlew: command not found
aishwaryat@Linux-1:~/EasyReimbursement$ gradle app:dependencies
The program 'gradle' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install gradle
aishwaryat@Linux-1:~/EasyReimbursement$
```

I installed the Gradle- View plugin to view the dependency tree of my project. I am not understanding how to detect duplicate entries, if any. Below is a screen shot of it.

[Project Dependency Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v12EH.png)

Comment: these problems some times get resolved by cleaning and rebuilding the project or use file-> invalidate caches/restart

Comment: Those were my initial attempts. Didn't work.

Comment: What is in your libs folder?

Answer (score 1):

Try to Clean your project : Build -> Clean

Or

In terminal execute in root project folder:

```
./gradlew clean
```

Comment: Cleaning, re- building, invalidate/ restart, none of these worked.